# Chrome JSON Extension does nothing

Tags: json, google-chrome

I installed the Google Chrome JSON extension. I then opened a local .JSON file. I don't see any syntax highlighting and collapse buttons. The file is being treated as plain text. Is there something I have to do to make Chrome treat it as JSON?

I'm on a Mac 10.9.2. Chrome Version 34.0.1847.116.

Answer (score 0):

I had failed to select the "Allow access to file URLs" checkbox in the Chrome extensions control panel for the JSON Extension. This is unchecked by default. I was trying to open local JSON files and seeing no formatting.

After checking this box, I was able to see JSON formatting on local files.

User error. (Though I'll bet other people get confused too.)